# How to wait for completion of NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that downloads a binary from a server and returns it.
But before the NSURLSession completes, my function is returning the value, so it's coming to be nil each time.
How can I wait till the download is complete and then return the binary?

Comment: You don't wait, instead you update in the completion routine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
NSURLSession *delegateFreeSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    [[delegateFreeSession dataTaskWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.example.com/"]
                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"Got response %@ with error %@.\n", response, error);
                           NSLog(@"DATA:\n%@\nEND DATA\n",
                                 [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                                         encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

                         [self loadDataToView:data]; // << your custom method inside the MyViewControllerClass
                       }] resume];
```

Comment: Why are you using weakSelf? The completion method is not retained by self, it is inline.

Comment: @zaph, thanks for pointig out. 'weak self' is not required here as the block is not retained/stored by self.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should take a callback as an argument. Once the NSURLSession completion handler gets the object you need, you call that callback with the data (or an NSError object if you got an error back from the server)

You can't 'wait' for execution to continue after you get the data. By definition, such network operations are handled asynchronously, hence the need for a callback.

Update: sample code below

```
- (void)getFeed:(NSDictionary*)parameters fromURL:(NSString*)url withCallback:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))callback {

    NSURL*newsfeedUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSMutableURLRequest *newsfeedRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:newsfeedUrl];
    [newsfeedRequest addValue:@"XMLHTTPRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];
    newsfeedRequest.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadNeewsfeedDataTask = [instance.session dataTaskWithRequest:newsfeedRequest completionHandler:^(NSData*data, NSURLResponse*response, NSError*error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSLog(@"statusCode %ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
        //Do something here in your completion handler and call your callback function when ready (either with the data you expected, or with an error object. Alternatively, you can outright refrain from adding a completion handler block and simply put your callback argument as the completion handler (they must have the same signature).
        callback(data, response, error);
    }];

    [downloadNeewsfeedDataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: I got the idea of what you're saying. I think that's exactly what I need. I shouldn't be "waiting" for the fetching of data. Could you tell me what to read so as to implement what you're saying?

Comment: I'm on my cell for the rest of the day, I'll expand the answer above with some code tomorrow. Important is for your code to be architected in such a way that you get away from the 'wait' pattern. You don't want to block a thread waiting for a result to come back (especially if it's the main UI thread). These problems are solved with either callbacks or background threads, which upon completion will update the UI appropriately and thus offer the user a good end user experience.

Comment: Luis, in case you get notified - I'm in the same boat as the OP. Don't understand where/how the callback would get utilized. In my case the NSURLSESSION method is called, downloads XML x, y coord values I then need to use in '- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { //code here to draw lines }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of completion handler for `NSURLSession`.

```
-(void) httpPostWithCustomDelegate{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/ajax-post/ajax-post.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString * params =@"name=Ravi&loc=India&age=31&submit=true";
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                          if(error == nil)
                                          {
                                              NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                              NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                          }

                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

[Here is good tutorial for NSURLSession.](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/#get-post)

Comment: This does not answer the question: "How to wait for completion".

Comment: in a way he does,  I believe that in the setup of the nsurl session, he puts the session in the main queue